# Typescript assumes the property type to be T | Properties["key"] instead of just T

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Say we have a type defined like so:

```
type PropsBase<T> = {
    optionalProp?: T;
} 

type Props<T, TAdditionalProps extends object> = PropsBase<T> & TAdditionalProps
```

Basically I have a common properties object and then child classes can add some more properties if they need them.
Then I want to use it like that:

```
type State<T> = {
    value: T;
}

abstract class Base<T, TAdditional extends object = {}> {
    state: State<T>;
    constructor(props: Readonly<Props<T, TAdditional>>) {
        this.state = {
            value: props.optionalProp || this.fallbackValue() // ERROR!
        }
    }

    abstract fallbackValue(): T;
}
```

This causes the following error:

```
TS2322: Type 'T | Props<T, TAdditional>["optionalProp"]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
   'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 
   'T | Props<T, TAdditional>["optionalProp"]'.
```

If I make `optionalProp` not optional (remove `?`) then it works, it also works if I remove `Readonly` from constructor and just use `Props<T, TAdditional>` instead.

**So my question is**: why is this happening? and is there a way to still use `Readonly` here and have an optional property?

P.S. I have `strict: true` in my tsconfig.json. I know that if I set it to `false` it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think switching from || to ?? fixes your problem.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZwEIENkQDwBUB8UAvFAN4BQUVUSwAlggHboA28SA-AFxS4Dc5AL5Ry5UJFiIUeADS8AggBNFdek1bsUUCAA9gERouQ0ARgCsIAY2CESmtJhwEoAMgXLVDZmynJR46ABlYHR9PFsySmoAN1YAVwgefiFRdBNkYDh0ayhLFkxjDCxZdxU1b209AyNTCxySUkFCCmooDNDEqGCO8IFWyyYMuDjrBDgACjBfHgAlCHRFJhYQbHsS3CUyr1Z8fABKSNbW4AALOmQAOnb9YkOj+9iWBJ4ppEvabZ8kKA4OKFPzhcAGasFgmbIAawAavEIOM9lF7oJEVBkSi0kNssAoCCWGDITCnnC9kkBMigA)

```
type PropsBase<T> = {
    optionalProp?: T;
} 

type Props<T, TAdditionalProps extends object> = PropsBase<T> & TAdditionalProps

type State<T> = {
    value: T;
}

abstract class Base<T, TAdditional extends object = {}> {
    state: State<T>;
    constructor(props: Readonly<Props<T, TAdditional>>) {
        this.state = {
            value: props.optionalProp ?? this.fallbackValue()
        }
    }

    abstract fallbackValue(): T;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, strict mode doesn't work very well. But my reason to use it was `strictBindCallApply` and `strictNullChecks`. So my answer is – set property by property:

```json
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "strictBindCallApply": true,
       "strictNullChecks": true
   }
}
```